# SSIS send mail task

Tags: ssis

Due to security policy my client is planning to stop the SQL mail service on the server, in that case will my SSIS mail task work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your SSIS mail will continue to work.

SSIS mail tasks connect directly to the SMTP server to send messages via the [SMTP connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137684.aspx) defined in your SSIS package.

Answer (score 1):

Send mail task in SSIS will be the best option to use and will have some restrictions but can send a formal mail without any delimiters,HTML tags by providing the SMTP server name